# Polchinski Eq 3.2.4 and Eq 3.2.5: Deforming contours in path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, complex-numbers, wick-rotation, analyticity

Here is the section of the book I'm talking about. I'm confused about the following two points:

- (i) Why is the path integral oscillatory?
- (ii) What does it mean, "we can deform contours just as in ordinary integration"?

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration on the complex plane? If not, learning about that is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes I am familiar! So this is just that as long as you don't hit a singularity you can deform the contour?

Comment: Yes, and at risk of putting too much "answer" in a "comment," note that the quantity in square brackets is $i$ times the action, and the action is real, so that exponential is a pure phase...